# Bind ObservableCollection to database

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have the following class:

```
[Table]
public class myClass
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

And the following code in order to load the data from my database table "myClass":

```
static public readonly ObservableCollection<myClass> items;
DataContext dataContext = new DataContext("Secret");

var ruleTable = dataContext.GetTable<myClass>();

IQueryable<Rule> custQuery = ruleTable.Select(tableName => tableName);
items = new ObservableCollection<myClass>(custQuery);
```

How can I make the database update based on my `ObservableCollection`?

Answer (score 0):

Bind the items to a ListBox with an ItemTemplate or any other ItemsControl.

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Content="{Binding ID}"/>
                <TextBox Content="{Binding Type, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Set the datacontext in code behind:

```
myListBox.DataContext = items;
```

Then add a button with an event that executes dataContext.SubmitChanges

Comment: nonono you explain how to bind the collection to UI. I want to bind it mySqlServer

Answer (score 0):

This codeproject article I wrote a while back has a section that details performing database update / delete / insert operations from a bound WPF datagrid:

[WPF DataGrid Practical Examples](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx#layered)